# How should I share a rate limited client between many separate scripts?

Tags: python, rate-limiting

I have a third-party API client that already comes with a built-in rate limiter. For my use case, I'll be running multiple different programs on a single machine that all want to access the same API.

I'm a bit overwhelmed with the options that I found. The options I have found so far:

- Instantiating a server that has a single instance of the third party client and build some custom messaging around it
- Disable the native rate limiter of the third party client and instead wrap it with a distributed rate limiter
- Using one the many queueing libraries like Huey or Celery, albeit from what I saw so far, they don't really seem to be designed to keep alive a single instance of anything (and it's probably inefficient to instantiate the third party client for every single call that I want to make).

What approach should I take and why?

Comment: All three options seem reasonable. Pick the one that fits your needs the best. I would argue that option 3 is really just option 1 with bells on.